# How to process audio bytes to extract MFCCs from a live audio stream?

Tags: python, machine-learning, audio, mfcc

I want to stream live audio from an inbuilt microphone and have been successful doing so using PyAudio and Sounddevice. Both the approaches are fine, but the main issue is about feature extraction.

*PyAudio*:

```py
import pyaudio

FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100
CHUNK = 1024

audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = audio.open(format=FORMAT,
                    channels=CHANNELS,
                    rate=RATE,
                    input=True,
                    output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
data = stream.read(CHUNK)
```

*Sounddevice*:

```py
import sounddevice as sd

fs=44100
duration=5

audio = sd.rec(duration*fs, samplerate=fs, channels=1, dtype='float64')
sd.wait()
print('audio recorded')
```

I want to obtain this live audio stream of data to extract MFCCs feature without writing the stream to a wave file and reading back. How to convert the stream data to MFCC features?

Addition: I have tried using Librosa library to obtain mfccs with PyAudio audio stream, but get the an error:

```py
while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    data_int = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    mfcc_y = librosa.feature.mfcc(data_int, sr=44100)
    librosa.display.specshow(mfcc_y, sr=44100)
```

I get an error: `ParameterError: Audio buffer is not finite everywhere`

I hope to get some guidance on how to convert audio bytes to be able to perform any feature extraction.

Comment: Your question is "how do I compute the MFCC coefficients from an audio stream."  The answer is either (1) find a library, and see if it can do so, or (2) do it yourself.  StackOverflow does not do library recommendations, so we can't help on 1 until you have picked a library.  On 2, you have not appeared to try anything MFCC related, so again, we cannot yet help you.

Comment: @wnoise "On 2, you have not appeared to try anything MFCC related, so again, we cannot yet help you." That's not strictly true. We are allowed to answer every ontopic question. There is nothing holding us back. The question might still be a bit broad though.

Comment: I have tried multiple things, explored different libraries and tried different ways. Check my previous question on same topic : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68279016/pyaudio-audio-stream-data-conversion-to-mfcc
I did try to compute mfcc with Librosa library and have added the error message there. But since none answered or comment so posted new question without librosa details to widen my hope for a helpful guidance.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sounddevice as sd
import librosa

fs = 44100
seconds = 10

myrecording = sd.rec(int(seconds * fs), samplerate=fs, channels=1)
sd.wait()
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=myrecording.ravel(), sr=fs, n_mfcc=40)
```

**I have also same problem so I got this solution.**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I need to to this excact thing but using pyaudio.. any ideas?